# how can i put header and page no. in pdf export data

Tags: javascript

code here:

```
function generatefromtable() {
            //var imagedata = 'aa.jpg'
     // var doc = new jsPDF();
            var data = [], fontSize = 12, height = 5, doc;
            //var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'A4', true);
            doc.setFont("times", "normal");
            doc.addPage()

            doc.text(20, 20, 'this page for our compony details or docture details');
            //doc.Image();
           // doc.addImage(imagedata,'jpg',15,40,180,160)
            //doc.text(100,10,"hello");

            doc.setLineWidth(1)
            doc.line(20, 30, 500, 30)
            doc.setTextColor(0, 0, 255)
            doc.setFont('courier')
            doc.setFontType('bolditalic')
            doc.setFontSize(22);
           // doc.text(0, 20, "Patient Daily Report");
            doc.setTextColor(100)
            doc.setFontSize(fontSize);
            data = [];
            data = doc.tableToJson('tbl');

            height = doc.drawTable(data, {
                xstart : 10,
                ystart : 10,
                tablestart : 50,
                marginleft : 5,
                xOffset : 5,
                yOffset : 15
            });
            doc.setTextColor(0, 0, 255)
            doc.text(250, height + 20, 'Patient Daily Report');



            doc.save("Patient_Daily_Report.pdf");
        }
   function generatefromtable() {
            //var imagedata = 'aa.jpg'
     // var doc = new jsPDF();
            var data = [], fontSize = 12, height = 5, doc;
            //var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'A4', true);
            doc.setFont("times", "normal");
            doc.addPage()

            doc.text(20, 20, 'this page for our compony details or docture details');
            //doc.Image();
           // doc.addImage(imagedata,'jpg',15,40,180,160)
            //doc.text(100,10,"hello");

            doc.setLineWidth(1)
            doc.line(20, 30, 500, 30)
            doc.setTextColor(0, 0, 255)
            doc.setFont('courier')
            doc.setFontType('bolditalic')
            doc.setFontSize(22);
           // doc.text(0, 20, "Patient Daily Report");
            doc.setTextColor(100)
            doc.setFontSize(fontSize);
            data = [];
            data = doc.tableToJson('tbl');

            height = doc.drawTable(data, {
                xstart : 10,
                ystart : 10,
                tablestart : 50,
                marginleft : 5,
                xOffset : 5,
                yOffset : 15
            });
            doc.setTextColor(0, 0, 255)
            doc.text(250, height + 20, 'Patient Daily Report');



            doc.save("Patient_Daily_Report.pdf");
        }
```

Comment: fix code format

Answer (score 0):

Consider the below example.

```
 var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');

    var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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';

    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'J

PEG', 20, 20, 20, 26);

pdf.text(50, 40, "Header");

pdf.addHTML(document.body,40,100,function() {
    pdf.save('web.pdf');
});



    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>

    <body>
        <p id="to-pdf">HTML content...</p>
    </body>
```

Hope it may help you.